# warning: Model XX has auth with authStrategy public of which is not yet supported in DataStore

Tags: aws-amplify

Here is my GraphQL schema:

```
type XX @model
@aws_cognito_user_pools
@aws_iam
@auth(
  rules: [
      { allow: owner, operations: [create, read, update, delete] },
      { allow: public, provider: iam, operations: [read] },
      { allow: private, provider: userPools, operations: [read] }
  ]
){
id: ID!
data: String!
}
```

I have two auth providers, Cognito user pools and IAM. Cognito for authenticated access and IAM for un-authenticated access. the first line in the rules' section is for the authenticated owner, the second line is for un-authenticated access and the last line is for authenticated non-owners. but when I run "amplify codegen models" the above warning rises.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm not sure what the impact is but to me it seems that when data is set to pools, and you query with graphql you get data back, but when you query via DataStore nothing returns.